# While trying to connect SMTP host , got this error SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, smtp, gmail, jakarta-mail, imap

***DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "smtp.gmail.com", port 587, isSSL false
DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response, THROW:
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset***

```
void replyToEmail(String subject, String text, String mailFolder = "INBOX",
                      String host = configProvider.getEMAIL_RECIPIENT_HOST(),
                      String user = configProvider.getEMAIL_RECIPIENT_USERNAME(),
                      String password = configProvider.getEMAIL_RECIPIENT_PASSWORD()
    ) {
        Session session = setSessionConfigurationAuth()
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps")
        store.connect(host, user, password)
        // Open mail folder
        Folder folder = store.getFolder(mailFolder)
        folder.open(READ_ONLY)


        String replyText
        if (mimeMessageParser.hasPlainContent()) {
            replyText = mimeMessageParser.plainContent
        } else if (mimeMessageParser.hasHtmlContent()) {
            replyText = mimeMessageParser.htmlContent
        }
        replyMessage.setText("\n$text".concat("\n").concat(replyText))

        // Send out email reply
        Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp")
        try {
            //connect to the smpt server using transport instance
```

> While connecting it fails here

```
            t.connect(user, password)
            t.sendMessage(replyMessage, replyMessage.getAllRecipients())
        } finally {
            t.close()
        }
        log.info('Replied email to ' + receivedMsg.getReplyTo())

        closeEmailConnection(folder, store)
```

}

Comment: Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall issue, but without the exception it's difficult to even guess.

Comment: @arnt This is an exception DEBUG SMTP: exception reading response, THROW: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Comment: There's actually quite a bit more information in an exception than that, including a stack trace. But look for a firewall issue.